# How to use Azure Web App and Microsoft Extension Logging to log Scopes in to Azure Analytics?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, azure-web-app-service, azure-analytics

I am trying to use a very simple setup to log my Asp.Net core application events into Azure Analytics. I am using Windows App Service with NetCore 6.0.
Everything is working fine, I can see my logs in the AppService Log Stream and Log(Analytics) AppServiceAppLogs table but when I use Scopes for logging like below code, these values are not showing in the logs.

```
    using (logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "user" , "Alex" } }))
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Test Log");
    }
```

I had to add below configuration in Program.cs to see the scopes in the LogStream

```
    builder.Services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.IncludeScopes = true;
    });
```

but cannot get see them in the Azure Analytics workspace.
Anyone has any experince with using scopes/strucutured logging with Azure Analytics and AspNet.Extesions.Logging ?

I tried using Serilog and I am getting nice structured josn log in console on my local machine but again no luck with Azure Analytrics and LogStream.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `v-regandowner` for the [code reference](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/ilogger.md#aspnet-core-applications).

You can use the `ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider` to log scopes in Azure Analytics.

The `ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider` supports log scopes.

Scopes are enabled by default. If the scope is of type `IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<string,object>>`, then each key/value pair in the collection is added to the Application Insights telemetry as custom properties.

> **Log Scopes in Analytics**
> using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["

To use scopes/structured logging with Azure Analytics and `AspNet.Extensions.Logging`, you need to follow these steps:

1. Add the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights` NuGet package to your project.
2. Configure the `ApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions` to include scopes.
3. Use the ILogger interface to log messages with scopes.

Use the below Packages.

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.17.0"/>
```

Sample code

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddLogging(builder =>
       {
            builder.AddApplicationInsights(options =>
                 {
                    options.IncludeScopes = true;
                 });
             builder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>(
             typeof(Program).FullName, LogLevel.Information);
       });

     var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
     var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

     using (logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "user", "username" } }))
         {
                logger.LogInformation("Test Log");
         }
```

[image]

For further information refer to [MSDoc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger) and [MSDoc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/scope).